# How can I create polygons in Farseer?

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics, farseer

I always get many error messages when I want to create polygons in Farseer.

> 'FarseerPhysics.Common.Vertices' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreatePolygon'    'FarseerPhysics.Factories.BodyFactory' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Instance'    The name 'physicsSimulator' does
>   not exist in the current context   The name 'triangleGeomtry' does not
>   exist in the current context   The name 'GeomFactory' does not exist in
>   the current context    The name 'physicsSimulator' does not exist in the
>   current context

What is wrong?
How can I create polygons in Farseer?

```
        triangleSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("triangle"); // Load the Sprite
        data = new uint[triangleSprite.Width * triangleSprite.Height]; 
        triangleSprite.GetData(data);
        verts = Vertices.CreatePolygon(data, triangleSprite.Width, triangleSprite.Height); 
        polygonOrigin = verts.GetCentroid(); 
        triangleBody = BodyFactory.Instance.CreatePolygonBody(physicsSimulator, verts, 3);
        triangleBody.Position = new Vector2(400, 600);
        triangleGeomtry = GeomFactory.Instance.CreatePolygonGeom(physicsSimulator, triangleBody, verts, 0);
```

Comment: What is physicsSimulator and triangleGeometry? You need to define them first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I'm doing it.. Using XNA 4 and Farseer 3.3.1

```
        //List of vectors defining my custom poly
        Vector2[] vlist = 
            {
                ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(25,0)) 
                ,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(15,25)) 
                ,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(-15,25)) 
                ,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(-25,0))
                ,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(-15,-10))
                ,ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(new Vector2(15,-10))
            };

        //get farseer 'vertices' from vectors
        Vertices _shapevertices = new Vertices(vlist);

        //feed vertices array to BodyFactory.CreatePolygon to get a new farseer polygonal body
        _newBody = BodyFactory.CreatePolygon(_world, _shapevertices, _stats.Density);
```

I'm defining the shape myself but I know farseer has tools included that will give you the 'vertices' object based on a sprite if you want to do that.

The texture to polygon section [here](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation) runs through how to do that.